# Django -- connect docker container with local postgres database

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, docker-network

Hi everyone i was working in a django project with docker. and i have a problem to connect
docker container with postgres database, one the the way to connect is network_mode: host but i want to connect using custom network.

```yaml
version: '3.3'

services:
  web:

    restart: always

    container_name: main
    command:
      - /bin/bash
      - -c
      - |
        python manage.py makemigrations  accounts
        python manage.py migrate
        python manage.py runserver
    image: main
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/main
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    extra_hosts:
      - "dbhost:172.17.0.1"
    networks:
      - backend
networks:
  backend:
volumes:
  static:
```

Comment: The database isn't running in a container; it's directly on the host?

Comment: yes database is on local machine not in docker container

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Docker Desktop with WSL2 you can use `host.docker.internal` other than that you need to get the Gateway Ip from here: `docker network inspect bridge` it might be `172.17.0.1`. Also to do this you don't want to use a specific network in your compose file but use the default one.

Comment: i tried this it dosen't work i came to knew we have to make chage in postgres pg_hba.conf file, Do you have any idea about it